# Upload a file and email it with PHP?

Tags: php, html, email-attachments

What is the easiest way to upload a file with this: `<input type="file" name="clanlogo">` and email it to "12345@email.com" I have researched, but have found super complicated codes and stuff. I need it to send as an attachment. In PHP. Here is the code i have so far:

```
<?php

## CONFIG ##

# LIST EMAIL ADDRESS
$recipient = "my email Here";

# SUBJECT (Contact Form/Remove)
$subject = "Volunteer Form";

# RESULT PAGE
$location = "thank_you.html";

## FORM VALUES ##

# SENDER
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

# MAIL BODY
$body .= "First Name: ".$_REQUEST['first_name']." \n";

$body .= "Last Name: ".$_REQUEST['last_name']." \n";

$body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['email']." \n";

$body .= "Volunteer Choice: ".$_REQUEST['dropdown']." \n";

$body .= "Questions: ".$_REQUEST['comments']." \n";
# add more fields here if required

## SEND MESSGAE ##
```

I just need some code to add to it that will allow me to upload a file.

Comment: write some code, when you get stuck, then ask. don't expect others to write it for you.

Comment: sorry, i thought i added the new part, wait a sec

Comment: Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer to do the actual mailing portion. Building your own MIME emails is painful and highly error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com) class and try this...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPMailer - Mail() basic test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();     
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "12345@email.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail()";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$destination);

$mail->AddAttachment("$destination");  //Your attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

- This is an example from PHPMailer Class

Answer (score 1):

Use the html form and add the tag `<input type="file" name="uploaded">` and then you can handle the file in PHP like so:

```
<?php

$file = $_FILES['uploaded'];
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
// do something
}
// do something

?>
```

I can't write a huge code, this should be a push for you to start out! Here is a quick [guide](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php). Now to attach it, you do this as an ajax request to the server, store the file's path and then extract the path again from the database when sending the email.

Comment: will this work for the hole thing? $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];